# Mailchimp PHP 2.0 not adding name fields

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm trying to add several fields  to a list in Mailchimp. This code is working, except 'FNAME', 'LNAME', and 'ADDRESS' aren't inserting (showing up blank in list after checking Mailchimp site). 'PHONE' and 'SIGNUPLINK' are inserting. Is there a formatting issue, or other?

```
        $Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
        $Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );

        $l_merge_vars = array( 
            'FNAME'     => $l_fname,
            'LNAME'     => $l_lname,
            'ADDRESS'   => $l_addresscombo,
            'PHONE'     => $l_phone,
            'SIGNUPLINK' => $l_signuplink
        );

       $l_subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe(
            $list_id,
            array('email' => $l_email), // 
            $l_merge_vars ,
            'html', 
            false,     // 
            true        // 
        );
```

'EMAIL' is also working.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (without knowing how the actualy setup looks alike), you have to set them up on MailChimp first, before they are being picked up. There's even a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAQhUZyzARs) for custom fields; one can also set [default values](https://mailchimp.com/help/set-default-merge-values/) for them or hide them from the signup form.

---

`$merge_vars` may need a field `MM1` which is the list ID.

Comment: Thank you for messaging; they are set up on Mailchimp as text fields;

Comment: The mere problem is that API v2 is obsolete and so one can't even find documentation or examples on their site; migrating to API v3 would make their v3 documentation applicable.